# How to train a neural network with different types in data?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, training-data

I'm facing a problem like I want to train a neural network to determine when a plant is fully grown by the height and some other stats. But there are so many types of plants so I cannot train one by for each of them.
I also tried to use a neural network trained with data of a species on another species and it didn't work. So I'm about to train a single neural network that can work with different species. But then each species has different ratios, for example:

```
plant      height    root radius
```

```
chili      45-50cm   1-2cm

red_bean   25-30cm   0.5-1cm 
basil      35-45cm   1-1.5cm
```

The ratio of plant height and root radius is different.

I don't have the ratio of all species so I was thinking about adding a new type param into the input so with each type, the network will figure out the ratio itself. Type param may be like 1 stand for chili, 2 for red bean, 3 for basil, etc.. but don't know if it works or not.

So is anyone here ever try that before or is there another way for it?

Answer (score 0):

Tags like that are not great candidates for simple NN's, but if you want to try it, (and you will), have a separate input for each tag. Set the input corresponding to the species of the training datum to 1 and all the others to -1.

Comment: Thank for your answer but I'm still can't figure out how to actually run it after training with tags like that. In real data then the input tag will always be 1 for each species, isn't it?